# How to redirect to other version of the checkout page on PayPal-Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working on a project, where I have to fix a PayPal hosted checkout.
When the user initiates a new checkout from the merchant page, he gets redirected to the sandbox version of the PayPal checkout page. My problem is that I want to redirect the user to an other version of this page. Url looks like this:
[https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&useraction=commit&token={some_token}](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&useraction=commit&token=%7Bsome_token%7D)
[current_checkout_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POTUD.png)
I'd like to change this current page to this new checkout page:
[alternative_checkout_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AVXk.png)
I'm not sure if I need to change the value of hostedCheckoutSpecificInput>>variant in the payload of the request, or something else is needed to be changed.

Comment: What is alternative about the "alternative checkout page" ? You provide no visual basis for comparison in your question, or explanation of the difference between the two. Also you haven't included any information about how you are setting up this checkout and redirecting the user to it to begin with, so it will be very difficult to offer any specific guidance.

Comment: thank you @PrestonPHX for taking your time! I included two screen shots in my question for the two checkout pages. The main difference is that on the current one, in the cart dropdown I'm not able to show neither the value of the Order > References > Descriptor (this is one property of payload of the CreateHostedCheckoutRequest) nor the content of the Cart (Order > ShoppingCart). On the "alternative" page in the dropdown these information could be shown. I develop it in Ruby, and I use this gem: https://github.com/Ingenico-ePayments/connect-sdk-ruby

Comment: I use the API reference to assemble the request https://epayments-api.developer-ingenico.com/s2sapi/v1/en_US/ruby/hostedcheckouts/create.html?paymentPlatform=GLOBALCOLLECT#hostedcheckouts-create  The response of the request contains a url, it looks like this: pay1.preprod.secured-by-ingenico.com/checkout/{code_to_identify_checkout}:{code_to_identify_checkout} I redirect the user this way: https://payment.{+the received url} There the user gets automatically redirected to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token={token}

Comment: I suspect that in the last link i should have something else instead of cmd=_express-checkout.  On the https://payment.pay1.preprod... page there is a from with hidden input fields, one of them looks like this ` <input type="hidden" value="101" name="variantCode">` Shouldn't it be something else?

Comment: If you share each API request body and response body, we can comment on any difference.